# SetValue 64bit machine registry

Tags: c#, .net, installation, registry, 64-bit

I want to set a value for 'NoModify' in below registry path.
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\XXXX"

I am using below code and it works only for X86 machines. Can you see any reason why this is not working for x64 machines?

```
// This value is correct
RegistryView registryView = releaseFlags.Contains("PLATFORM_X86") ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;

    using (RegistryKey hkeyLocalMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView))
    {
        RegistryKey noModifyKey = hkeyLocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{xxxx}", true); //SL: Key Name

        if (noModifyKey != null)
        {
            noModifyKey.SetValue("NoModify", 0);
            noModifyKey.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Elaborate on "not working".  Does it set the value in the wrong registry, does it fail with an error?  Don't keep us in the dark.

Comment: what is releaseFlags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my mistake in the code.

```
RegistryView registryView = releaseFlags.Contains("PLATFORM_X86") ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
```

Should be as follows:

```
RegistryView registryView = releaseFlags.Contains("PLATFORM_X86") ? RegistryView.Registry32 : RegistryView.Registry64;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are on a 64 bit machine and your app is 32 bit - it should store these settings in the HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node instead of the HKLM\Software\ node.

Answer (score 2):

You should open base key in this way.
It works for me.

```
var rk = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) {
        rk = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
        var val = rk.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Pourab\\sanjande", true);
    
        val.SetValue("test", "testvalue");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as you compiles your .NET program as `x86` not `AnyCPU`, you will be using the "correct" registry keys meant for x86 in any circumstances because it will be running as x86.

If you compile it as `x64` or `AnyCPU`, it could be quite tricky because it will probably run as x64 on an x64 machine and uses the "wrong" registry where `HKLM\SOFTWARE` for x86 programs is *actually* `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node`.