# Register key works in windows8, but gets null value in windows10

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am working with winforms and using web browser to open web page.  Program works perfectly in windows 8, but in Windows 10, I am getting null value in register key value. I am using load event handler, this is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var appName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + "WindowsFormsApplication2.exe";
   var Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
 @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"
          ,true);
   Key.SetValue(appName, 11000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
   Key.Close();
}
```

Maybe any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DevNewb yes it is internet explorer 11, for microsoft edge it is 11001, but it is still not working.

Comment: How are you compiling your program? `AnyCPU`, `x86` or `x64`? You're probably using the "wrong" registry as 64-bit programs will be under `HKCU\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node...`. [See here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337577/setvalue-64bit-machine-registry).

Comment: @Equalsk i tried this, it is still not working, maybe something should be different when I am using virtalbox? But i checked path is the same

Comment: "It is still not working". How? Do you get an error? What actually happens?  Please describe the exact problem in detail.

Comment: @Equalsk My key is getting null value(I debugged it). It throws NullreferenceExpectation was unhandled.

Comment: Then they key doesn't exist, you don't have permission or you're using the "wrong" registry as described above. If you answer my question about how you're compiling I might be able to be more specific. I can't think of anything else that causes this issue.

Comment: @Equalsk I find on the internet that one of windows 10 flash update KB313272 can cause this problem

Comment: I genuinely hope that works for you because as long as you keep failing to answer any questions then nobody can help you.